# compiler error when running "wmake" in project folder

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors

when I open a terminal, switch to my project directory (which is in my home folder) and run the command "wmake" I get the error:

g++ -m32 -Dlinux -DWM_DP -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter
-Wold-style-cast -O3  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -IphaseModel/lnInclude -ImultiphaseSystem/lnInclude -ImultiphaseFixedFluxPressure -IinterfacialModels/lnInclude -I/opt/openfoam221/src/transportModels -I/opt/openfoam221/src/transportModels/incompressible/lnInclude -I/opt/openfoam221/src/transportModels/interfaceProperties/lnInclude -I/opt/openfoam221/src/transportModels/incompressible/lnInclude -I/opt/openfoam221/src/transportModels/incompressible/singlePhaseTransportModel
-I/opt/openfoam221/src/turbulenceModels -I/opt/openfoam221/src/turbulenceModels/incompressible/LES/LESModel -I/opt/openfoam221/src/turbulenceModels/LES/LESdeltas/lnInclude -I/opt/openfoam221/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude -IlnInclude -I. -I/opt/openfoam221/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/opt/openfoam221/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -Xlinker --add-needed -Xlinker --no-as-needed Make/linuxGccDPOpt/multiphaseEulerFoam.o
-L/opt/openfoam221/platforms/linuxGccDPOpt/lib \
         -lmultiphaseSystem -lcompressibleMultiPhaseModel -linterfaceProperties -lincompressibleTransportModels -lcompressibleMultiphaseEulerianInterfacialModels -lincompressibleLESModels -lincompressibleRASModels -lfiniteVolume -lOpenFOAM -ldl   -lm -o /opt/openfoam221/platforms/linuxGccDPOpt/bin/multiphaseEulerFoam /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file /opt/openfoam221/platforms/linuxGccDPOpt/bin/multiphaseEulerFoam: Permission denied collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [/opt/openfoam221/platforms/linuxGccDPOpt/bin/multiphaseEulerFoam] Error 1

This error occured the first time today, yesterday everything compiled fine for me.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have write permissions in the folder `/opt/openfoam221/platforms/linuxGccDPOpt/bin`? How about the permissions on the resulting executable file?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: No. Is that the only problem? I'll change permissions and see what happens.

Comment: If you don't have permissions to write, then you can't write, it's that simple. :)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I m wondering since yesterday everything worked fine. Could you tell me how to give myself all permissions to the folder and its contents since doing it with "gksudo nautilus" takes an eternity, because I would have to do it for every file seperately.

Comment: If you're in the group, give the group write permissions, otherwise give the world write permissions. The last is not such a good idea, so adding yourself to the group and make sure the group have write permissions is probably the best bet. Go to your favorite search engine (or http://superuser.com/) and search there for how to do it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Problem is: The group is root itself - I can t add myself to the group root I guess right? Therefore i would have to change the group itself first and this I would have to do for all folders and files within folder "/opt/openfoam221/platforms/linuxGccDPOpt/bin", right?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Edit: I tried "sudo chown -R USER /opt" and made myself owner of the folder and all contents. Now I can compile again! Will you past an answer - so I can mark the question as solved?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Will you write an answer so I can accept it?